# How to remove every 12 zeros from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list as follows:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I would like to remove zeros that repeat 12 times in a row from the list to have the desired output of

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I tried using index but soon realized this would also remove zeros that dont repeat 12 times...

```
index = [0]
new_a = np.delete(a, index)
print(new_a)
```

Comment: What would you do, for `[0] * 13 + [1]`, which means, replace both 13 zeros or keep one of them

Comment: In that case I would like to replace (remove) 13 zeros and keep 1. so basically keep zeros that are between two nonzero numbers but remove them if they are next to a zero.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

Every line can be well understood.

```py
buffer = []
result = []
for n in num:
    if n == 0:
        buffer.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        if len(buffer) < 12:
            result.extend(buffer)
        result.append(n)
        buffer = []
if len(buffer) < 12:
    result.extend(buffer)
```

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

### Trick Answer

- Using the regexp
- You can learn it at [python.re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```py
import re
line = "".join(str(n) for n in num)
ans = re.sub(r"0{12,}", "", t)
res = [int(n) for n in ans]
```

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect job for [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
     1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

from itertools import groupby, chain

a = list(chain.from_iterable(G for k,g in groupby(a)
                             if len(G:=list(g))!=12 or k!=0))
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

*NB. this requires python's (≥3.8) [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) syntax.*

How it works.

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will group consecutive values, if the values are not `0` or if the group size is not 12, keep the group. Then [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) all groups back to a single list.

Note that the order of the expressions in the test is important. `len(G:=list(g))!=12` should be first to ensure it is always evaluated and thus that `G` is being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its a generalization so you can delete sequences of n zeroes from the list:

```
def remove_n_zeroes(lst, n):
    counter = 0
    new_lst = []
    for num in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[num]!=0:
            if counter<n:
                new_lst.extend([0]*counter)
            counter = 0
            new_lst.append(lst[num])
            continue  # keeps the counter from incrementing 
        counter+=1
        if counter == n:
            counter = 0
    if counter < n:   # Handles the trailing zeroes
        new_lst.extend([0] * counter)
    return new_lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one line solution and no extra library needed.

Convert list `a` to a string, replace 12 zeros to empty string, then convert it to a list of integer.

```py
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = ''.join(map(str, a)).replace("0"*12, "")
c = list(map(int, b))
print(c)
```

or

```py
print(list(map(int, ''.join(map(str, a)).replace("0"*12, ""))))
```

```py
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```